# Count number of rows with having... SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, having

I have to count if UserId is listed one or more times and if one put +1 to "new users" else "+1" to "returning users".

Have I have done:

```
select 
Count(distinct [UserId]) as 'Unique users'
from [TelemetryData] 
where [DiscountId] = '8CAEA860-6766-43E2-9280-27AFE7FDF82E' and [EventName] = 'DiscountClick'

/* returning */
select
count(Id) as 'Returning users'
from [TelemetryData] 
where [DiscountId] = '8CAEA860-6766-43E2-9280-27AFE7FDF82E' and [EventName] = 'DiscountClick'
group by [UserId]
having count(Id) > 1

/* returning */
select
count(*) as 'New users'
from [TelemetryData] 
where [DiscountId] = '8CAEA860-6766-43E2-9280-27AFE7FDF82E' and [EventName] = 'DiscountClick'
group by [UserId]
having count(*) = 1
```

I need count total numer of rows in "returning" and "new" users query like in first query. How to do it?

Comment: This looks like SQL Server code so I added that tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with two levels of aggregation.  Calculate the count at the `UserId` level, then use that information to get the counts you want:

```
select sum(case when cnt > 1 then 1 else 0 end) as ReturningUsers,
       sum(case when cnt = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as NewUsers
from (select UserId, count(*) as cnt
      from [TelemetryData]
      where [DiscountId] = '8CAEA860-6766-43E2-9280-27AFE7FDF82E' and [EventName] = 'DiscountClick'
      group by UserId
     ) u
```

Comment: its not working 'cnt' not found. select sum(case when 'cnt' > 1 then 1 else 0 end) as 'ReturningUsers',
       sum(case when 'cnt' = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as 'NewUsers'
from (
 select 
  [UserId], 
  count(*) as 'cnt' 
    from [TelemetryData]
    where [DiscountId] = '8CAEA860-6766-43E2-9280-27AFE7FDF82E' and [EventName] = 'DiscountClick'
    group by [UserId]
 )

Comment: @Nerf use whole query. with `u` in the end

Comment: Oh right. What is 'u'? I thought it was misstake and removed it ;D

Comment: Now how I can insert this select to another select? I'm getting error with "exists"...